# How can I show or hide Fields in redux-form based on some condition triggered by an event

Tags: reactjs, redux, conditional-statements, rendering, redux-form

I have the following form, which contains a Field and a FieldArray. Inside the FieldArray I have a select field, with two options: Demo and Final. When Demo is selected, I would like to hide the Maintenance Period and Maintenance Type Fields and when Final is selected, the Demo Duration field should be shown, the previous 2 should be hidden. The code is below:

```
const renderLicenses = ({ fields }) => (
    <ul className="list-unstyled">
        <li>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add License</button>
        </li>
        {fields.map((license, index) =>
            <li key={index}>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    title="Remove license"
                    onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}/>
                <h4>License #{index + 1}</h4>
                <Field
                    name={`${license}.licenseName`}
                    type="text"
                    component={renderSelectLicenses}
                    collectionOfOptions={LICENSES}
                    label="Please select license name">
                </Field>
                <Field
                    name={`${license}.licenseType`}
                    type="text"
                    component={renderSelectLicenseType}
                    label="Please select license type"/>
                <Field
                    name={`${license}.validFrom`}
                    type="text"
                    component={renderCalendar}
                    label="Valid from"/>
                <Field
                    name={`${license}.validTo`}
                    type="text"
                    component={renderCalendar}
                    label="Valid to"/>
                <Field
                    name={`${license}.demoDuration`}
                    type="text"
                    component={renderField}
                    label="Demo duration"/>
                <Field
                    name={`${license}.maintenancePeriod`}
                    type="text"
                    component={renderField}
                    label="Maintenance period"/>
                <Field
                    name={`${license}.maintenanceType`}
                    type="text"
                    component={renderSelectMaintenanceTypes}
                    collectionOfOptions={MAINTENANCE_OPTIONS}
                    label="Maintenance type"/>
            </li>
        )}
    </ul>
);
```

This is the renderSelectLicenseType code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    const renderSelectLicenseType = ({input, label}) => (
    <div className="form-group">
        <label>{label}</label>
        <select className="form-control" {...input}>
            <option disabled>Please select a license type</option>
            <option value="demo">Demo</option>
            <option value="final">Final</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    );

export default renderSelectLicenseType;
```

Basically, I would like to have an onChange event on select and hide/show the other fields if the event.target.value is 'demo' or 'final'. I do not know how to propagate this event to the other fields that are self contained:

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
<div className="form-group">
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
        <input className="form-control" {...input} type={type} placeholder=  {label}/>
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
</div>
```

);

Finally, this is the code for the master component that holds the entire form:

```
render() {
        const {handleSubmit, invalid, submitting} = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))} style={tempStyles}>
                <Field name="machineID" type="text" component={renderField} label="Machine ID"/>
                <FieldArray name="licenses" component={renderLicenses} />
                <div className="form-group">
                    <RaisedButton type="submit" label="Add new machine" primary={true} disabled={invalid || submitting}/>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'addMachine',
    validate: validate
})(AddMachineMaster);
```

I am new to redux-form and having a difficult time trying to figure this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redux-form is already attaching the `onChange` prop to your `select` field: it's one of the props you're passing with `{...input}` here:

```
<select className="form-control" {...input}>
   <option disabled>Please select a license type</option>
   <option value="demo">Demo</option>
   <option value="final">Final</option>
</select>
```

Which means that your value is already in the Redux store. You need however to extract it using `connect`, since newer versions of `redux-form` don't connect your form with every value to increase performance.

There's an example in the docs that does exactly what you want. In this case when an Email field is checked an input to enter email address is shown, and hidden otherwise.

http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/selectingFormValues/

The gist of it is decorating your form twice, one with `reduxForm` and another with a manual `connect`. In this specific mapping from state to props, you can use the selectors provided by `redux-form` to extract exactly the form value you want and inject it as a prop.

That prop can be passed on to the component you want to show/hide.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this strategy - when using redux tools, i saw that the value from the select was being saved in the store through the form's reducer. However, I did not know how to extract it and use it again in the form to decide what will be hidden. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Redux-form is getting a bit strange for my taste, specially for the not so obvious form. And IMO for mainstream forms it's trivial to handle it yourself, so I'm not using it as much as I did nowadays. ;)